# ng-init set property value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular js version 1.5. I am also using https://www.npmjs.com/package/username node package to get the current logged in user in my electron app.

Here is what i have done till now.

```
  $scope.getUserName = function() {
    Promise.resolve(username()).then(function(value) {
      console.log(value); 
      $scope.currentUserName = value;
    }, function(value) {
      // not called
    });
  }
```

The above function is defined in the main controller. I am using an ng-init to get the username as soon as the app loads by doing something like

```
<body ng-controller="MainController" ng-init="getUserName()">
 <p> Welcome, {{currentUserName}}
</body>
```

but the `currentUserName` is always being returned as null. What my googling tells me is this - that I am trying to read the value of `currentUserName` before its being set.

In order to resolve that issue, I used `$watch` in my controller but I am still getting the currentUserName as undefined. Here is the code

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.$watch("currentUserName", function(){
    $scope.getUserName();
    console.log("Welcome user: " + $scope.currentUserName);
  });
 //additional functions are here
}]);
```

Can you please let me know what I might be doing wrong here ?

Thanks and Regards
Gagan

Comment: Does your console or debugger show any discrepancies with the value returned by the `username()` being resolved? If the issue likes within the scope then it is a much more isolated solution rather than guessing at your nodejs not functioning properly

Comment: ng-init in the same div than the ng-controller seems weird. Why don't you call getUserName(); in the controller ? I'm not sure ng-init is really called, try to put an alert in it.

Comment: @AGE : nope . the correct value is returned.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant can you please let me know what's weird about it. I am a noob and anything you say will be helpful - thanks

Comment: Did you try initializing currentUserName as an empty string in your controller?

Comment: @NMittal : I am not sure if that is going to help. However i have done as you suggested and now i get an empty string instead of undefined.

Comment: @Gagan: The scope is defined when the controller is set, and ng-init will be applied to a sub-scope. (the $scope in a sub div isn't the $scope of the parent div, it inherits it). For me, ng-init has no effect at all where you put it.

Comment: Is getting you promise resolved? what that console.log() prints?

Comment: @MartinJimmyHlavňa - yes the promise is getting resolved. The current user is getting printed to the console.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant . if I do a console.log('hello world" ) in the ng-init , it is getting printed to the console. Rest everything same. In that case, shouldn't I think its having some effect ?

Comment: And if you try to call $scope.getUserName(); in your controller instead of ng-init (that would be also a cleaner solution IMHO) .

Comment: @MartinJimmyHlavňa - it could be. But my intention is to get the username as soon as the app loads. AFAIK ng-init is the way to do for these scenarios, isn't it ?

Comment: Another thing that comes to my mind - Maybe the $digest is not getting invoked. You can try to add $scope.$apply() in that Promise.resolve callback after you set $scope.currentUserName.  Maybe you can use AngularJS Batarang plugin to check if $scope is being changed.

Comment: @MartinJimmyHlavňa when i did that, i got my username printed to the console 7806 times .. and electron app crashed.. because its still printing my username to the console :)

Comment: Yeah I thinked that could happen... so the $digest should be working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102526/discussion-between-martin-jimmy-hlava-and-gagan).